# What are the best and worst cases of 3-Way Quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I found that in 3-Way QuickSort, the best case is O(n), when every element is equal and worst case is O(n²), that I have no idea what is.

It's the one using a single pivot, not the dual pivot.

The site I was reading this from: https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/quick-sort-3-way.

Comment: I seem to remember two different algorithms that may be termed `3-Way QuickSort`: *dual pivot* and a modification of the single pivot quicksort that partitions into less than, equal to, and greater than the pivot: please clarify by editing the question which one you want to discuss. The latter handles duplicate keys nicely and has *same key in all items* as one best case instead of a worst case. Can you give a tight asymptotic bound for that case? can you achieve the same for dual pivot quicksort?

Comment: @greybeard 3-way quicksort most probably refers to sorting of all 3 subparts i.e. dual pivot

Comment: @mangusta:  A. Nitto edited the question to explicitly state `the one using a single pivot, not the dual pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

Find a median pivot element to prevent the extreme pivot cases which cause the O(N*N) complexity. Therefore, the worst-case complexity is improved to O(N*logN). The 3-way quicksort only accounts for the case of equal elements.